# Developing custom Talend component : how to create something REALLY custom that doesn't require input or output?

Tags: java, components, talend

In order to connect to a soap API to get some analytics data, I have to use a custom librairy and custom code to trigger the request and download the result as a CSV file.

PoC is done outside of Talend and everything is working perfectly.

Now I need to integrate that stuff into a Talend job. To dev something the most simple as possible without redeveloping process already included in Talend.

For instance, I want to develop a simple component, that takes basic credentials in params, and just execute a query and download the csv result.
Then I'll be able to use a tFileInputDelimited to parse the csv file and continue my Talend job.
And it works at some point but I can't clean the hacks I've made for this second PoC to work... Because Talend prevent me to do that.

---

Reading all the (few) documentation on it (

- https://talend.github.io/component-runtime/main/1.1.12/index.html,
- http://repo.apache.maven.org/maven2/org/talend/sdk/component/documentation/1.1.3/documentation-1.1.3-all-in-one.pdf

)

I figured out that you can create ONLY 3 types of components.

- An Input Component [I] => that takes no Input, It automatically triggered if doesn't depend on some parent job, and it MUST be followed by another component to process it's result.

  ```
  [I] --> (...)
  ```
- An Output Component [O] => That takes a input, but has no output (like a row logger for example). As it depend on a parent component, it can't be run by itself.

  ```
  (...) --> [O]
  ```
- An hybrid component called Processor [P], that's nothing more than an output component, that can also produce something as a result, so it can be chained with another one (but that's not mandatory). But as it is just a alternative version of the output component, it must depend on a parent

  ```
  (...) --> [P] --> (...)
  ```

Well, let list what I need my component to do, and see what fits the best:

1. It has to be able to trigger itself, because it doesn't need any input
2. It has to send a "onComponentOk" event when it's job is finished
3. It must not require any output component, because the result is not something to chain to a next one, but just a signal to say "hey, the csv file is ready, find it where you know"

Yeah! perfect. Now let's find which type of component fit each requirements :

1. => Input Component
2. => Input, Output and Processor Components
3. => Output and Processor Components

So which one fit all this requirements? No one...

---

*(For simplification purpose, let's consider Output and Processor components are the same thing for the rest of this post.)*

So I tried the two possible implementation:

- Using a Input Component, it will works properly. But Talend wont compile my job if I don't wire another component after mine. So that's crappy but I must have a component that (don't) use my (non) result in order to build the job.....
  It drives me crazy.
- Using a Processor Component, it will work properly, this time I don't have to wire another component after. BUT, my component init routine will never run if it doesn't receive any data. So I have to wire a fake component that feed (no) data into my component (that require nothing) to start. bhwaAAAAAAAA !!!

So I read everything I can find on the subject, even trying some mystical rituals. But I can't find any (clean) solution!

I also tried messing around with the Talend toolkit Java annotations, to disable input or output.

HELP, if someone knows a secret tips about Talend toolkit, my ears are wide open.

But I think the answer is to reconsider the problem.
Because it comes from my requirement that doesn't fit the Talend possibilities.
I know I should produce a result data. But why redevelopping the tFileInputDelimited ??? I will have to maintain more code, and I don't want duplication.

In the perfect world, a solution would have been to just send the output csv file path to the next component. But unfortunately the tFileInputDelimited doesn't seems to be able to set its config from previous component output.
But I might be wrong. To be honest I just started working with Talend 2 weeks ago. I know only like 1% of the stuff.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Talend seems to have changed a lot of things with their new component kit.. I've developed custom components for TOS 6.x, some of which are as you described, not requiring any input and not producing output, and it was not that complicated to do.

Comment: take a look how they implemented: tJava or tDbConnection  those don't have input/output links, just triggerinput / triggeroutput

Comment: @BalazsGunics Yeah, that's what I looked into before anything else... But I never find a clean way to require and import the libraries I needed :/

Answer (score 0):

There are likely workarounds using globalMap to passthrough the filename between components accross jobs and reuse tFileDelimited.

However it sounds like your component is just an input which shoukd use commons-csv or another lib to read the file "on the fly" and avoid temporary files - reuse, no duplucation ;).
Why encapsulating it? Because it makes the format encapsulated in your component and the jobs more stable. You also dont want to propagate a local file path between components but records already loaded in memory, this will enable to deploy your component in Talend Pipeline Designer and run in the cloud directly later on if desired. Note that even in the studio, it reduces potential issues due to side effects around the job (file is not owned by the job but your filesystem).

The only small tip can be to disable some validations if you dont want to build an output, dataset and datastore since by default the plugin encourages good practises but studio tolerates to disable these ones enabling you to just do an input. That said a datastore and dataset have value for this component since you will be able to use them as templates/metadata in the studio.

At the end it will only require to change the input in your jobs instead of rewiring them with a pre-job. So it sounds it is likely simpler on the long run in terms of maintenance to just go with an input IMHO.